# how get information from website in C# for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I need to get live information like news, photos, content, videos link, and etc from the website and display it on my app.

Please let me know how to do it. I saw some samples, they get info using web client. mostly its for string content. for me, i display some photos and some other reference link and etc.,

Anyone help me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the site from which you want to fetch the data. Many popular sites implement their own API's for providing the data. For example, [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com) and [Facebook API](http://developer.facebook.com).

And the data is provided to us in the form of XML or JSON in general, which you need to parse in your app and show it in your UI.

Note: Whatever may be the data format(images or videos), they are provided as the http links which you need to supply as the source to your UI components.

For example, insert an image tag in UI

```
<image Name="myImage"/>
```

and then after parsing your web response, supply its source from your response like this

```
myImage.Source = response.imageSource;
```

(This is just for an overview, not a complete solution)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review the Code Samples here :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

Your question is very broad as there are many factors involved in creating a Windows Phone application so you need to look at various samples, take the bits you want from those samples and then create something, it is very difficult to create an app for someone in a forum post, this is why you are not going to get a direct answer to your question.